# How can I store MongoDB data to a javascript variable?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
var liveJSON = [];
Player.find({teamName: req.query.homeTeam}, function(err, foundHomePlayers){
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        liveJSON = foundHomePlayers;    <<<<------ HERE!
    }
});
```

I want to store MongoDB data (foundHomePlayers) to a javascript variable (liveJSON). But this syntax doesn't work? How can I store whole foundHomePlayers to a javascript variable?

Comment: have I answered your question? I was surprised not to hear back from you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are misunderstanding that callbacks are asynchronous, and won't fire until the event that triggers them occurs, so trying to store the mongo data in a global variable is useless - as in your example.

```
var liveJSON = [];
Player.find({teamName: req.query.homeTeam}, function(err, foundHomePlayers){
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        liveJSON = foundHomePlayers;    <<<<------ HERE!
    }
});
liveJSON // This will not be defined yet because the callback is async
```

My alternative suggestion is that you trigger a function that can process the `liveJSON` data once it is fetched instead of relying on a global variable:

```
function doSomethingWithLiveJSON(liveJSON) {
    console.log(liveJSON);
}
Player.find({teamName: req.query.homeTeam}, function(err, foundHomePlayers){
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        doSomethingWithLiveJSON(foundHomePlayers);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, because of node.js follow asynchronous nature it does't wait for reply from mongodb callback . 
if you want to save mongodb data into javascript variables create some function to store data into variables

```
var express=require('express');
var mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var app= express();
var url="mongodb://localhost:27017";
var g=[];
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{

mongoClient.connect(url,(err,db)=>{
var mydb=db.db('mongopract');

mydb.collection('practice').find({name:"solkar"},{projection:{_id:0,name:1,id:2}}).toArray((err,result)=>{
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }else if(result.length){
        storedata(result[0].name);   
res.send('info'+JSON.stringify(result[0].name));
    }else{
      res.send('no data found');
    }
})
})

});


function storedata(x){
    g.push(x);
console.log(g);
}

var PORT=process.env.PORT||3001;

app.listen(PORT,()=>{
    console.log('port numebr'+PORT)
});
```